# R studio: can't find function although the function is listed in my list of files in working directory

Tags: r, function, directory

This is what I call in the command line:

```
cash_flow_generator(1)
list.files(getwd())
```

So what could cause this problem other than wrong working directory?
This is what the command line return if I rund this code:

```
> # build cash flows
> cash_flow_generator(1)
Error in cash_flow_generator(1) : 
  could not find function "cash_flow_generator"
> list.files(getwd())
 [1] "cash_flow_generator.R"                        "check.R"                                      "FinancialMath.pdf"                           
 [4] "function.R"                                   "ggplot2 2.png"                                "ggplot2.png"                                 
 [7] "Kopie van Overzicht kost vredegerechten.xlsx" "net present value.R"                          "net present value_v2.R"                      
[10] "net present value_v3.R"                       "reverse calculation.docx"                     "reverse NPV calculation.jpg"    

"
```

This is my function:

```
cash_flow_generator <- function(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    result <- "Positive"
  }
  else if (x < 0) {
    result <- "Negative"
  }
  else {
    result <- "Zero"
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading the function into your environment. In your particular case, you should do:

```
cash_flow_generator<-function(parameters){list.files(getwd())[1]}
```

Where I wrote parameters, you should include the parametres of your function. Hope that solved your problem.

Comment: Not sure why you made that line of code, but when I added : source("...mydir/cash_flow_generator.R") to my main calling script it indeed worked. Thx. Indeed, loading it into the environment is what I missed out on.